# Utilities.parseCsv() 'Could not parse text' (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm really confused because this was working earlier and I don't know why it is broken now. I've got CSV files that I'm trying to parse. I'm accessing them using the following code:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
```

It crashes on that 3rd line. When debugging, I see everything looks normal... `file` is an object, `csv` is a string and based on the preview I think the format looks correct for a CSV (`'header1,header2,header3 data1,data2,data3 data4,data5,data6...'` etc). Then, however, `data` is undefined. What could be causing this error? I'm not finding much online and debugging didn't provide me with any good insight.

Are there particular symbols in the CSV that would break this function perhaps? There are `'` and `"` symbols in the CSV data... but I don't know why that should matter.

**UPDATE:**
My file in question has about 16000 lines. I'm currently going through it in segments trying to narrow down the problem. But it isn't quotes; I ran a test with the parser as follows and it worked as expected:

```
function myFunction() {
  var a = 'test""123,456\n';
  var b = "abc' 'def,ghi\n";
  var h = 'x,y\n';
  var str = h+a+b;
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(str);
  Logger.log(str);
  Logger.log(csv);
}
```

The log file looked like this (expected):

```
x,y
test""123,456
abc' 'def,ghi

[[x, y], [test""123, 456], [abc' 'def, ghi]]
```

If you have any more ideas to test as to what might be causing this, I can test them.

Comment: The quotes will matter. try replacing the outer ones with double quotes and have no more double quotes in the string and check.

Comment: I updated my question. It would be really difficult to test that in the file itself, but I tested both cases in a separate test function and it worked fine. Still hunting down the problem manually...

Answer (score 1):

I tried testing your function slight modified and it looks like it works okay.  Here's the one I used.  If you can share the data file with us, I'd be glad to take a look at the problem.

```
function prrrrse() 
{
  var br = '<br />';
  var a = 'test""123,456\n';
  var b = "abc' 'def,ghi\n";
  var h = 'x,y\n';
  var str = h+a+b;
  var delimiter = ',';
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(str,delimiter);
  var s = 'str=' + str + br + 'delimiter=' + delimiter + br;
  for(var i = 0;i<csv.length;i++)
  {
    s+='csv[' + i + ']=';
    for(var j=0;j<csv[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(j>0)s+=' , ';
      s+=csv[i][j];
    }
    s+= br;
  }
  dispStatus('Parsing',s, 800, 600); 
}


function dispStatus(title,html,width,height,modal)
{
  var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
  var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 400;
  var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
  var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
  var modal = typeof(modal) !== 'undefined' ? modal : false;
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(width)
     .setHeight(height);
 if(!modal)
 {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
 }
 else
 {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, title);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I just found the problem... Turns out there are indeed commas in some of the data. Time to go through and figure out how to remove those when creating the csv file I guess. But if anyone ever needs to know how to find which rows of data have the wrong number of commas, open the csv in Notepad++, hit Ctrl-F, change the `Search Mode` to `Regular expression` and the tab to `Mark`. The regex `^[^,\n]*((,[^,\n]*){6}$)` will find all instances with 6 commas. Change 6 to however many you should have. Then mark all and look for the non highlighted rows.

Comment: Yes I use the editor Ultraedit regularly for resolving issues like that.  In fact, I often try to pick wierd delimiters made from characters that are extremely unlikely to be found in my data.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I just had a similar problem crop up, and after trying to find an errant comma, ended up with a simpler solution. Line 18,000-something (out of 20,000+) in the csv somehow had an extra line break (`\n`) in it. Eliminating the line break solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same problem today and discovered that trailing spaces at the end of some lines were causing the parser to fail. I resolved this with this regular expression: `csvString.replace(/[ \t]+$/gm, '')`

Answer (score 0):

I would generally suggest splitting lines temporarily and giving each of them to parseCsv to see which one is causing an issue. Then revert back your code.

```
  var lines = responseText.split('\n');
  for (i in lines) {
    var line = lines[i]
    Logger.log(line);
    Utilities.parseCsv(line, ',')
  }
```

In my case Utilities.parseCsv was unable to parse strings including escaped double-quotes (\")

Sample string:

```
2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z,"500100801","game.block.puzzle","Drop Number \"2048\" Merge Block","615d701d541dae701f87c46c","Drop Number 2048",7.65
```

Where this one works without any issues:

```
2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z,"500100801","game.block.puzzle","Drop Number '2048' Merge Block","615d701d541dae701f87c46c","Drop Number 2048",7.65
```