# Could not Parse text in Utilities.parseCsv using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I am beginner to google apps script. I am trying to import CSV file from Zipped attachement from gmail. I am getting error Could not Parse tex at Line of code

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(unZipBlob.getDataAsString(), "\t");"
```

I have tried all combinations Like UTF -8 and other unicode to solve the issue but unable resolve it. even i tried the answer mentioned at Link

[Utilities.parseCsv() 'Could not parse text' (Google Apps Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067877/utilities-parsecsv-could-not-parse-text-google-apps-script)

Below I have attached my code . can some one please help me to resolve?
Please let me know if you need further details to help

```
function importCSVFromGmailMC1() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('GOC "CM pacing Report" - 1*');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0].copyBlob();
  attachment.setContentType('application/zip');
  var unZipBlob = Utilities.unzip(attachment)[0];
  unZipBlob.setContentType('text/csv');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('mysheetid').getShee tByName('CM pacing_daily');

  if (unZipBlob.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(unZipBlob.getDataAsString(),"\t");
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your csv sample

Comment: Hi my CSV is text file which is unzipping correctly. and I am getting error only in utilities.parsecsv statement. Below is my some of the text sample                             "Column1","column2",